# NullPointerException in Java while trying to print an array

Tags: java, arrays, exception, nullpointerexception

The thing is that I'm trying to print the matrix previously created in the constructor, but seems that it's empty.

Here's the code of the constructor:

```
public Matrix(int row_col){
    int [][] randomMatrix = new int[row_col][row_col];
    Random rand = new Random();
    if (row_col > 0 && row_col < ROW_LIMIT && row_col < COL_LIMIT)
    for (int i = 0; i < randomMatrix.length; i++) 
     for (int j = 0; j < randomMatrix[0].length; j++)
         randomMatrix[i][j] = rand.nextInt(51);
}
```

And the code of the method print:

```
public void print(){
    int row = randomMatrix.length;
    int col = randomMatrix[0].length;
    for(int i=0 ; i < row ; i++)
     for(int j=0 ; j < col ; j++)
        System.out.print(randomMatrix[i][j]);
}
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
int [][] randomMatrix = new int[row_col][row_col];
```

by

```
this.randomMatrix = new int[row_col][row_col];
```

The constructor initializes and fills a *local variable* instead of initializing and filling the *instance field* used by the `print()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now seems to work, but in a strange way. I set the dimension to 2x2, but when I call to the print method, it prints such a huge chain of numbers... do I have something wrong in the constructor?

Comment: @Ziitox what else do you expect? you never call `System.out.println()` or have a `"\n"` in your output when using your `print()` method.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like randomMatrix is defined directly in the scope of the constructor, and is not being stored in a field of the class.

If you already have a randomMatrix as a field, remove the int[][] in the first line of the constructor method, so you refer to the field instead of declaring a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is beacuse you have declared and initialized your array `randomMatrix` inside your constructor and as soon as the contructor's code is executed your `randomMatrix` array goes out of scope of `print` method.

And so when you try to access it in `print` method there is no such `randomMatrix` object, so you get `NullPointerException`